# How to map [[String:AnyObject]] to a class from a string

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to add an Array of objects from a string. I am getting an encrypted string from an API call. After decrypting the data, getting as a string of JSON structure as below:

```
{
     "request_id”:”abcds123”,
     "status”:”18”,
     "message":"SUCCESS",
     "customer_name”:”XXXX X XX”,
     "mobile_no”:”123456789”,
     "email_id":"xxx@xxx.com",
     “function”:
                [
                 {“funcCode”:”OPN”,,”funcVal”:0,”funcType":"M"},
                 {“funcCode”:”CLO”,”funcVal”:1,”funcType":"M"}
                ],

     “dataID”:”ASD1234”,
     ”valid”:”Y”
}
```

This is generic API response which will very based on response.
I can map "function" element  to [[String:AnyObject]]. But not able to map it to class directly. Do we have an easier approach to extract  "function" array to a class in swift without iterating the data and add to an array variable:

```
var mainObject : [String:Any] = [:]

if let data = result.data(using: .utf8) {
  do {
    mainObject =  (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any])!

    if let status = mainObject[“status”] as? String {
      switch(status) {
      case 200:
        if mainObject.keys.contains(“customer_name”) {
          //do something
        }
        if mainObject.keys.contains(“function”) {
          if let functionList = mainObject[“function”] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
            //map functionList to class [Function]
            for function in functionList {
              print(“Function ====> ", function)
              //create a class and add to an array of Function class
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
  }
}
```

The result string coming from response.

Objective is to extract "function" data alone and map it to  class without creating container class/struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State of the art is the `(De)Codable` protocol, you can decode JSON dictionaries directly into structs

```
struct Main: Decodable {
    let status, customerName: String
    let function : [Function]
}

struct Function: Codable {
    let funcCode, funcType: String
    let funcVal : Int
}
```

---

```
let data = Data(result.utf8)
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let mainObject = try decoder.decode(Main.self, from: data)
    print(mainObject.customerName)
    print(mainObject.function)
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Note: A JSON dictionary is never `[String:AnyObject]` in Swift 3+, it's `[String:Any]`

---

Edit: If you want only the `Function` struct keep the `JSONSerialization` code,  omit the `Main` struct, declare `mainObject` as

```
var functions = [Function]()
```

and map the JSON array

```
if let functionList = mainObject["function"] as? [[String:Any]] {
   functions = functionList.map {Function(funcCode: $0["funcCode"] as! String,
                                           funcVal: $0["funcVal"] as! Int,
                                           funcType: $0["funcType"] as! String) }    
}
```

To write the array to UserDefaults encode it with `JSONEncoder` to `Data`.

Comment: Thanks Vadin for the quick response.As I mentioned, response may very. I am interested to map the  function data without creating a Main struct, as I have some scenarios to extract the data from mainObject variable and add it to userdefaults.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) protocol that will help you to map your JSON data into objects.

First create your structs:

```swift
struct MyFunction: Codable {
    let funcCode: String
    let funcVal: Int
    let funcType: String
}

struct MyContainer: Codable {
     let status: string,
     let message: string,

     // Another properties

     let function: [MyFunction]
}
```

Then you just have to map your JSON string to the object using the decode function:

```swift
if let jsonData = result.data(using: .utf8) {
  do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let mainObject = try decoder.decode(MyContainer.self, for: jsonData)
  } catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
}
```

For more information you can check out this [blog post](https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/).

Comment: Thanks Yannick for the quick response and formatting my code.As I mentioned, response may very. I am interested to map the  function data alone without creating a MyContainer struct, as I have some scenarios to extract the data from mainObject variable and add it to userdefaults.

Comment: @SJMC Just create a `struct`, it will always make your code more readable.